# Do Australian power tools need a converter to be used in Philippines?

Tags: australia, power, philippines

I'm sending an Aussie drill and grinder 240v to the Philippines. Do I need to buy a power converter from 110v to 240v to run power tools safely?

Comment: Says [here](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/philippines/electricity) that the Philippines also uses 220-240V, just like Australia...  Where did you get 110V?

Comment: Are you sure they are brushed/series-universal motor or brushless motor tools and not AC induction motor tools? AC induction motors might not like the *frequency* change as the Oz grid is 50Hz and the Philippines use 60Hz due to US influences...

Comment: Is this travel related? I can't imagine a tourist from the Phillipines going shopping for power tools in Australia, or an Aussie tourist wanting to do some DIY while on holiday in the Phillipines.

Answer (score 2):

Electricity in the Philippines runs between 220V, so your power tools might me slightly underpowered but not by much. What I would highly recommend though is a surge protector since my experience is that power varies more than other places there, in both voltage and frequency. Officially the power is [220V at 60 Hz in the Philipines](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/) but I've gotten 210 to 230V input.